# Preparing a Perl file to run with Ubuntu and tabix

Tags: perl, ubuntu, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, vcftools

I don't know about Ubunto or Perl but still need to install and run a program on it.
This is what I am looking at: http://vcftools.sourceforge.net/docs.html

On the installation section it says this:

> To build the vcftools executable, type "make" in the vcftools folder.
>
> The Perl scripts require that VCF files are compressed by bgzip and
>   indexed by tabix (both tools are part of the tabix package, available
>   for download here). Both tools must be in directories that are listed
>   in the PATH environment variable. For running the Perl scripts, the
>   PERL5LIB environment variable must be set to include the Vcf.pm module
>
> export PERL5LIB=/path/to/your/installation/perl

so Ok, I extracted and copied their VCFtools folder into ubuntu's home folder. Then I said "make" it gave errors, then I went and downloaded that tabidx tool, but from this point I don't know what to do with it, Ok I download tabidx, but what to do next and how?

Thanks.

Comment: Next, you should try to fix the errors you got.

Comment: If you have a plain Ubuntu install, it doesn't even have `make`, so you should install that first. `sudo aptitude install build-essential` will pull in `make` and some other common development tools, but there will probably be more stuff to install.

Comment: @tripleee : it says "sudo: aptitude: command not found"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find / -name Vcf.pm
```

If that gives one--and only one line--you can do this:

```
export PERL5LIB=$( dirname $( find . -name Vcf.pm ))
```

Comment: found two: 
"/root/vcftools_0.1.9/lib/perl5/site_perl/Vcf.pm"   AND ALSO 
"/root/vcftools_0.1.9/perl/Vcf.pm"

Comment: @BDotA, I would probably go with the `site_perl` path.